# Reading And Writing Windows Registry in C++ (How to convert string to wchar(?))

Tags: c++, winapi

This is a part of my assignment. I know how to open/read registry keys and create values, but i have few questions. My code:

This is how i write new string value into registry:

```
void lCreateKeyOne(HKEY hKey, LPCWSTR lSubKey)
{
WCHAR wcValue[] = TEXT"testvalue";
LONG lNewValue = RegSetValueEx (hKey, 
                                L"MytoolsTestKey", 
                                NULL, 
                                REG_SZ,
                                (LPBYTE)wcValue,                    
                                sizeof(wcValue));
}
```

It works, but i want to generate random string and write it into registry key.
This is how i generate random string:

```
static const char alphanum[] =
"0123456789"
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

int stringLength = sizeof(alphanum) - 1;

char genRandom()
{
return alphanum[rand() % stringLength];
}
srand(time(0));
string Str;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
   Str += genRandom();
}
```

1. How to write it as registry key ?
2. how to convert string Str to WCHAR wcValue[] ?
3. I tried to use char instead of wchar and it writes chinese characters
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexa

Comment: 1) If you want to use `char`s instead of `WCHAR`s, why can't you use [`RegSetValueExA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexa)? Or not define `UNICODE` macro in your project? 2) This is **not** [tag:c]. C doesn't have `string`. Why did you tag C?

Comment: Use a `std::wstring` rather than a `std::string` for `Str`. I *think* that should work as a direct drop-in replacement.

Comment: Rather than do what you ask in the question, sidestep the problem by never using 8 bit text in Windows

Answer (score 2):

```
static wchar_t const * const alphanum{
    L"0123456789"
     "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" };

constexpr auto stringLength{ wcslen(alphanum) };

wchar_t genRandom()
{
    return alphanum[std::rand() % stringLength];
}

// ...
std::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(std::time(nullptr)));

std::wstring Str;
for (std::size_t i{}; i < 20; ++i){
   Str += genRandom();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And what about NOT to use string or std::wstring,

```
static wchar_t const * const alphanum{
    L"0123456789"
     "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" };

constexpr auto stringLength{ wcslen(alphanum) };

wchar_t genRandom()
{
    return alphanum[std::rand() % stringLength];
}

// ...
std::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(std::time(nullptr)));

wchar_t Str[20+1] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Str[i] = genRandom();
}
```

> *I tried to use char instead of wchar and it writes chinese characters*

Because your method `RegSetValueEx` is reference to `RegSetValueExW` which received as wide character format. `sizeof(char) = 1` and `sizeof(wchar_t) = 2`, The value of two `char` characters is read as a `wchar_t` character(which as you see in chinese characters). You can specifically reference to `RegSetValueExA` if you want to try using `char`.